# In firebase functions, get the current https://domain part

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a firebase functions so that it will render a page based on the request path/url.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

function buildHtml (path) {
  return HTML_BODY_WITH_path_BEING_CONSIDERED
}

export const rendering = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, res) {
  const path = req.path
  res.send(buildHtml(path))
})
```

When I rewrite every source to this function, I could obtain `/colletion/1` as `path` then render the page, when I access `https://MY-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com/collection/1`.

What I can't figureout is how can I obtain the `MY-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com` part.

I fetched `req.domain` but it was `null`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since HTTPS functions are served by Express (and receive an express request object as a parameter, you'll want to use the request [`hostname`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname) in tandem with the request [`protocol`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.protocol) to build a URL that may be helpful to the caller.  These are both properties on the `req` parameter in your given code, which is an [Express Request object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

Comment: Yes. The link Doug provided gives you all the properties that Request object has. You can use the hostname property. I was just about to send similar answer :)